# javascript function not working in IE and firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a function written in javascript as follows,

```
<script>
function newPopup(url) {
        popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=1300,left=480,top=190,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes').focus();
}
</script>
```

And Its called like this within the href of a button

```
document.getElementById('user-help').href = 'Javascript:newPopup("<spring:message code="user.help.dashboard"></spring:message>")';
```

This works in Chrome and Opera. But doesn't work in IE and Firefox.In firefox just a blank page appears while in IE error called page cannot be displayed.
Can someone please give me a solution for this. I have searched, but did not find a favorable solution.

Comment: You should be a bit more specific than just the name of the browser. Please list the version numbers as well. e.g. Firefox 34, IE10, etc.

Comment: Remove all template things from your code and show us what the actual browser sees in your question.  We can't possibly know what those template or server-side tags resolve to so can't possibly undestand what code is actually executing.

Comment: think of it as this, document.getElementById('user-help').href = 'Javascript:newPopup("www.google.com")';

Comment: Did your question get answered?  Can you mark one of the answers as the "best answer" by checking the green checkmark to the left of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
    <script>
    function newPopup(url) {
         var popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=1300,left=480,top=190,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
         popupWindow.focus();
    }
    </script>
```

And call like this,

```
document.getElementById('user-help').href = 'Javascript:newPopup("<spring:message code=\"user.help.dashboard\"></spring:message>")';
```

Hope it works for you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues.  **First off**, you have quoting issues in this:

```
"<spring:message code="user.help.dashboard"></spring:message>"
```

It isn't clear what you are trying to construct with that line, but that appears to be a syntax error to me.

**Second off**, you're trying to use that string as an URL for `window.open()`.  That isn't a valid URL.

**Third**, you have a typo in your `window.open()` function call.  There's an extraneous `=` sign in the calling args.

Comment: sorry that typo was a mistake while putting the question. this works well in chrome and opera. doesnot work in IE and firefox. the spring message is just a url taken from a parameter file.

Comment: @LahiruTjay - then please show us the ACTUAL generated code that the browser sees.  If `"<spring:message code="user.help.dashboard"></spring:message>"` is turned into something else before the browser sees it, then we need to know EXACTLY what the browser sees.  Use View/Source in the browser to see that code and then put that in your question.  We can't guess what that might get turned into.

Comment: this is what there is in the IE tab,  javascript:newPopup("/NetHelp/Documents/theinternetbankinginterface.html") In the chrome normal url is executed showing the result.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the window.open. There is an = sitting outside the spec parameter:

```
popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow',='height=700,
```

should be:

```
popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=700,
```